# Gerar e baixar links programaticamente

Tags: r

Há um banco de dados da Agência Nacional de Águas que pode ser acessado pelo [Hidroweb](http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/).

Para realizar o download é só acessar:

> Dados hidrológicos > Séries históricas

e incluir o código do posto pluviométrico desejado.

Quando escolhido o código e tipo do posto o site encaminha para uma página onde se pode realizar o download em `MSAccess` ou [texto](http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/Estacao.asp?Codigo=2043018&CriaArq=true&TipoArq=2).

Vale ressaltar que este link é igual para todos os códigos de postos, variando somente a parte `Codigo=""`, onde será inserido o código de outros postos que se quer baixar.

Como eu tenho centenas de postos a ser baixado, é muito dispendioso realizar o download um por um. Eu gostaria de realizar o download realizando um `loop`.

No entanto, o link mencionado anteriormente não é o utilizado para inserir na função `download.file()`, pois ele não redireciona diretamente para o download. O link que redireciona é aquele que se gera quando se escolhe o tipo de arquivo a ser baixado `MSAccess` ou `.txt` e aparece um link "Clique aqui". É gerado então um link tipo: `http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/ARQ/A20150425-173906-352/CHUVAS.ZIP`, onde `A20150425-173906` é a data e hora de quando o link foi acessado (desconheço o significado do `-352`).

Alguém saberia como eu poderia realizar o download com um código em R?

Comment: Bruno onde teriam os códigos dos postos? Usando Python você consegue facilmente um script para executar este "crawler" e baixar todas as informações que precisa.

Comment: Oi Arthur, 
os postos eu entraria com um vetor com o número deles que eu preciso. Então, depende da área de estudo. Como exemplo seriam esses códigos de postos 2851050,  2751025, 2849035, 2750004, 2650032, 2850015.

Comment: Bruno, eu também procuro uma função em R para abrir os arquivos zip gerados pelo hidroweb. Por acaso você conseguiu?
Obrigado.
Mauricio Camargo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segue uma resposta em R. Você vai precisar dos pacotes `httr` e `XML`:

```
install.packages("httr")
install.packages("XML")
```

Fiz o código de uma forma mais simples, sem criar funções ou colocar outros parâmetros que não o código da estação, mas com isso deve ser fácil fazer o resto. Como na resposta do Arthur Alvim, os arquivos serão salvos com o nome da estação na pasta de trabalho atual do R.

```
library(httr)
library(XML)

baseurl <-c("http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/Estacao.asp?Codigo=", "&CriaArq=true&TipoArq=1")

estacoes <- c(2851050, 2751025, 2849035, 2750004, 2650032, 2850015, 123)

for (est in estacoes){
  r <- POST(url = paste0(baseurl[1], est, baseurl[2]), body = list(cboTipoReg = "10"), encode = "form")
  if (r$status_code == 200) {
    cont <- content(r, as = "text")
    arquivo <- unlist(regmatches(cont, gregexpr("ARQ.+/CHUVAS.ZIP", cont)))
    arq.url <- paste0("http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/", arquivo)
    download.file(arq.url, paste0(est, ".zip"), mode = "wb")
    cat("Arquivo", est, "salvo com sucesso.\n")
  } else {
    cat("Erro no arquivo", est, "\n")
  }
}

# trying URL 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/ARQ/A20150910-005606-786/CHUVAS.ZIP'
# Content type 'application/x-zip-compressed' length 6532 bytes
# downloaded 6532 bytes
# 
# Arquivo 2851050 salvo com sucesso.
# trying URL 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/ARQ/A20150910-005607-172/CHUVAS.ZIP'
# Content type 'application/x-zip-compressed' length 6734 bytes
# downloaded 6734 bytes
# 
# Arquivo 2751025 salvo com sucesso.
# trying URL 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/ARQ/A20150910-005608-703/CHUVAS.ZIP'
# Content type 'application/x-zip-compressed' length 6737 bytes
# downloaded 6737 bytes
# 
# Arquivo 2849035 salvo com sucesso.
# trying URL 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/ARQ/A20150910-005609-783/CHUVAS.ZIP'
# Content type 'application/x-zip-compressed' length 3995 bytes
# downloaded 3995 bytes
# 
# Arquivo 2750004 salvo com sucesso.
# trying URL 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/ARQ/A20150910-005610-492/CHUVAS.ZIP'
# Content type 'application/x-zip-compressed' length 10751 bytes (10 KB)
# downloaded 10 KB
# 
# Arquivo 2650032 salvo com sucesso.
# trying URL 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/ARQ/A20150910-005613-538/CHUVAS.ZIP'
# Content type 'application/x-zip-compressed' length 4625 bytes
# downloaded 4625 bytes
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Parece robusto.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito bem!

Comment: @Molx, ao executar o código novamente obtive uma mensagem de erro: `No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.`. Pelo que verifiquei ele acontece ao em `r<- POST(url = paste0(baseurl[1], est, baseurl[2]), body = list(cboTipoReg = "10"), encode = "form")`. O que será que pode estar havendo?

Comment: @Jean Estou tentando ver o problema, mas parece que o sistema hidroweb está travando, e vi no site que eles estão mudando para uma nova plataforma. Sugiro que você já se adiante e comece a verificar como deve obter as informações no novo sistema, porque este script em breve deve ficar inútil de qualquer forma.

Comment: Concordo com você, e ainda estou pensando em como vou fazer para migrar para o novo sistema. Sobre a questão, acho que realmente é algo com a resposta do servidor, consegui contornar o problema inserindo um argumento `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` em content(r, as = "text"). Encontrei isto em  Dei uma olhada em: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Eu implementei em Python algo que pode te ajudar. Ele vai baixar o arquivo e nomeá-lo com o número do posto. Isso não responde a pergunta. Seria bom você fornecer um exemplo para que talvez alguém resolva seu problema no R.

```
# hidroweb.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# pip install beautifulsoup4
# pip install requests

import requests
import re
import shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Hidroweb(object):

    url_estacao = 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/Estacao.asp?Codigo={0}&CriaArq=true&TipoArq={1}'
    url_arquivo = 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/{0}'

    def __init__(self, estacoes):
        self.estacoes = estacoes

    def montar_url_estacao(self, estacao, tipo=1):
        return self.url_estacao.format(estacao, tipo)

    def montar_url_arquivo(self, caminho):
        return self.url_arquivo.format(caminho)

    def montar_nome_arquivo(self, estacao):
        return u'{0}.zip'.format(estacao)

    def salvar_arquivo_texto(self, estacao, link):
        r = requests.get(self.montar_url_arquivo(link), stream=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(self.montar_nome_arquivo(estacao), 'wb') as f:
                r.raw.decode_content = True
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
            print '** %s ** (baixado)' % (estacao, )
        else:
            print '** %s ** (problema)' % (estacao, )

    def obter_link_arquivo(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
        return soup.find('a', href=re.compile('^ARQ/'))['href']

    def executar(self):
        post_data = {'cboTipoReg': '10'}

        for est in self.estacoes:
            print '** %s **' % (est, )
            r = requests.post(self.montar_url_estacao(est), data=post_data)
            link = self.obter_link_arquivo(r)
            self.salvar_arquivo_texto(est, link)
            print '** %s ** (concluído)' % (est, )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    estacoes = ['2851050', '2751025', '2849035', '2750004', '2650032',
                '2850015', ]
    hid = Hidroweb(estacoes)
    hid.executar()

# saída
# ** 2851050 **
# ** 2851050 ** (baixado)
# ** 2851050 ** (concluído)
# ** 2751025 **
# ** 2751025 ** (baixado)
# ** 2751025 ** (concluído)
# ** 2849035 **
# ** 2849035 ** (baixado)
# ** 2849035 ** (concluído)
# ** 2750004 **
# ** 2750004 ** (baixado)
# ** 2750004 ** (concluído)
# ** 2650032 **
# ** 2650032 ** (baixado)
# ** 2650032 ** (concluído)
# ** 2850015 **
# ** 2850015 ** (baixado)
# ** 2850015 ** (concluído)
```

https://gist.github.com/arthuralvim/0779dda52e6d56d0d3eb

Comment: Bom, isso resolve sim. Muito obrigado Arthur.

Answer (score 2):

Gostaria de adicionar que em ambos os códigos, R ou Python, é preciso fazer uma pequena mudança para baixar dados de vazão e outros.

No R precisa mudar aqui:

```
  list(cboTipoReg = "10")
```

No Python:

```
  post_data = {'cboTipoReg': '10'}
```

A questão é que esse *hardcode* `10` é apenas para pluviometria (*CHUVA.ZIP*).
Se você quiser outros dados siga o dicionário abaixo:

> value="8" para Cotas (cm)
>
> value="9" para Vazões (m³/s)
>
> value="12" para Qualidade da Água
>
> value="13" para Resumo de Descarga
>
> value="16" para Perfil Transversal

Answer (score 1):

Incrementei alguns passos no script do Arthur, como alterar o caminho de trabalho e implementar as estações por um arquivo externo. Peço desculpa por qualquer "gaff", sou iniciante. Espero ter ajudado.

```
___________________________-> Python - Hidroweb <-______________________________

Autor: Arthur Alvin 25/04/2015
afmalvim@gmail.com

Modificação: Jean Favaretto 16/07/2015
jeanfavaretto@gmail.com

Modificação:Vitor Gustavo Geller 16/07/2015
vitorgg_hz@hotmail.com

______________________________-> Comentários <-_________________________________

O script Python HidroWeb foi criado  para automatizar o procedimento de aquisição 
de dados das estações do portal: http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/

Para utilizar o script deverao ser instaladas as bibliotecas:
-> requests
-> beautifulsoup4 (ou superior)

UTILIZACAO:

Apos a instalacao das bibliotecas cria-se um Arquivo de Entrada, com o numero 
das estacoes. A proxima etapa será inicilizar o script, entao ele abrir uma
janela para selecionar o Arquivo de Entrada. Como saída o HidroWeb - Python, 
retorna duas informacoes. A primeira em tela, contendo a situacao do download. 
Por fim, gera-se no mesmo diretorio do Arquivo de Entrada, os arquivos de cada 
estacao que foi possivel realizar a transferencia (baixada).


ARQUIVO DE ENTRADA:

A entrada deve ser um arquivo *.txt contendo o número das estação a serem 
baixadas, com a seguinte estrutura:
-> O número das estacoes defem ser digitadas linhas apos linhas, 
sem cabecalhos, sem espacos, nem separadores (, . ;).
-> Simplismente um Enter após cada numero de estacao. 

02751025
02849035
02750004
02650032
02850015


SAIDAS:

Situação das transferencias em Tela:
** 02851050 **
** 02851050 ** (baixado)
** 02851050 ** (concluído)

No diretorio do Arquivo de Entrada serao criados os arquivos de saida contendo
a informacao disponivel de cada estacao baixada.

OBS: Tenha certeza que todos numeros das estacao existam, caso contrario da 
"BuuuG".
Palavras chave: HidroWeb, ANA, Estacoes, Pluviometricas, Fluviometricas,
Precipitacao, Vazao, Cotas, baixar, download. 
"""

# ********  DECLARACOES INICIAIS
import os
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
import sys
import requests
import re
import shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# By Vitor

# ABRE ARQUIVO DE ENTRADA
root    = Tkinter.Tk()
entrada = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='r')    
root.destroy()

#****************---------------correcao de bug--------------********************
if (entrada == None): 
    sair = raw_input('\tArquivo de entrada nao selecionado. \n\t\tPressione enter para sair.\n')
    sys.exit()
#****************---------------fim da correcao--------------********************

pathname = os.path.dirname(entrada.name) #define o path de trabalho igual ao do arquivo de entrada
os.chdir(pathname)  #muda caminho de trabalho.

VALORES = []

# By Jean

while True:

    conteudo_linha = entrada.read().split("\n")
    VALORES.append(conteudo_linha)

    if (len(conteudo_linha) <= 1):
        break

print VALORES, "\n"


#### By Arthur

class Hidroweb(object):

    url_estacao = 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/Estacao.asp?Codigo={0}&CriaArq=true&TipoArq={1}'
    url_arquivo = 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/{0}'

    def __init__(self, estacoes):
        self.estacoes = estacoes

    def montar_url_estacao(self, estacao, tipo=1):
        return self.url_estacao.format(estacao, tipo)

    def montar_url_arquivo(self, caminho):
        return self.url_arquivo.format(caminho)

    def montar_nome_arquivo(self, estacao):
        return u'{0}.zip'.format(estacao)

    def salvar_arquivo_texto(self, estacao, link):
        r = requests.get(self.montar_url_arquivo(link), stream=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(self.montar_nome_arquivo(estacao), 'wb') as f:
                r.raw.decode_content = True
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
            print '** %s ** (baixado)' % (estacao, )
        else:
            print '** %s ** (problema)' % (estacao, )

    def obter_link_arquivo(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
        return soup.find('a', href=re.compile('^ARQ/'))['href']

    def executar(self):
        post_data = {'cboTipoReg': '10'}

        for est in self.estacoes:
            print '** %s **' % (est, )
            r = requests.post(self.montar_url_estacao(est), data=post_data)
            link = self.obter_link_arquivo(r)
            self.salvar_arquivo_texto(est, link)
            print '** %s ** (concluído)' % (est, )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    estacoes = VALORES[::1][0]
    hid = Hidroweb(estacoes)
    hid.executar() `
```