# R - Download de dados do portal Hidroweb

Tags: r, web-scraping

A Agência Nacional de Águas disponibiliza em seu portal [Hidroweb](http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/) o download de séries históricas referentes aos dados obtidos por diversas estações de monitoramento.

Gostaria automatizar o download dessas séries históricas, contudo a ANA alterou seu site e estou com dificuldades para realizar a tarefa. [Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60124/gerar-e-baixar-links-programaticamente) está o código em R que eu me baseei para baixar os arquivos.

A princípio eu havia substituído os links de `http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/` para  `http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/`, contudo, o download não está conseguindo ser realizado corretamente.

Imagino que o problema esteja na linha `r <- POST(url = paste0(baseurl[1], est, baseurl[2]), body = list(cboTipoReg = "10"), encode = "form")`, visto que o comando de `POST` parece não estar conseguindo acessar devidamente o link `http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/Estacao.asp?Codigo=2851050&CriaArq=true&TipoArq=1`.

Quando acessado com o query `&CriarArq=true&TipoArq=1` o site mostra apenas a mensagem "Solicitação não permitida", não sendo possível realizar o scraping da página para encontrar o arquivo .zip.

Eu havia imaginado que apenas o comando `POST` com a URL anterior e o form `cboTipoReg = '10'` bastaria, mas parece não estar acessando a página da maneira esperada. Alguém saberia me explicar o que há de errado?

Comment: Perguntas que dependem de recursos externos fogem do objetivo do site, mas você pode [edit] a questão e reduzir o problema a um [mcve] (simulando os dados localmente, por exemplo, de forma que a pergunta fique autocontida sem depender de recursos que podem mudar a qualquer momento, e de forma a não se confundir com suporte de APIs de terceiros).  Ao editar, a pergunta entra numa reavaliação da comunidade via voto.

Answer (score 2):

Oi

Podemos fazer de forma semelhante atualizando a url base para: "http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/rest/api/documento/convencionais?tipo=1&documentos="

**Sugestão em R:**

```
## Download automático dados de estações convencionais SNIRH -----

library(httr)

baseurl = "http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/rest/api/documento/convencionais?tipo=&documentos="
ListaEstacaoes = c(40025000,40050000,40070000,40100000)

setwd("D:/PastaParaDownload")
destino = getwd()

# tipo=1 arquivo access *.mdb
# tipo=2 arquivo texto  *.txt
# tipo=3 arquivo excel  *.csv
tipo = 1

#substituindo o tipo
baseurl = gsub("tipo=",paste0("tipo=",tipo),baseurl)

for(i in 1:length(ListaEstacaoes)){
  baseurl_est = paste0(baseurl,ListaEstacaoes[i])

  #Conexao
  r = POST(url = baseurl_est, body = list(cboTipoReg = "10"), encode = "form")
  if (r$status_code == 405) {
    cont = content(r, as = "text", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    download.file(baseurl_est, paste0(ListaEstacaoes[i], ".zip"), mode = "wb")
  }
}
```

Adicionalmente, para estações telemétricas:

```
## Download automático dados de estações telemetricas SNIRH -----

library(httr)

# URL Base 1 - gera o arquivo
baseurl1 = "http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/rest/api/documento/gerarTelemetricas?codigosEstacoes=&tipoArquivo=&periodoInicial=&periodoFinal="
# URL Base 2 - baixa o arquivo
baseurl2 = "http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/rest/api/documento/baixarTelemetricas?codigosEstacoes="

# Informação necessaria das estacoes telemetricas: ID Codigo
# para obter o ID consultas ficha descritiva da estacao em http://gestorpcd.ana.gov.br/ 
idEstacaoes     = c(84863570,91264360,84763570,84663550,94765311)
CodigoEstacaoes = c(15400000,15341000,15360000,15380000,15326010)

#setwd("D:/PastaParaDownload")
destino = getwd()

#Parametros necessarios e comuns as estacoes
    # Estacoes telemetricas disponiveis apenas em dois formatos
    #tipo = 2 # tipo=2 arquivo texto  *.txt
    tipo = 3 # tipo=3 arquivo excel  *.csv

    # Data de inicio e fim do recorte da serie no formato aaaa-mm-dd 
    dinicio = "2019-01-01"
    dfim = "2019-12-31"

    # Hora de inicio e fim do recorte da serie no formato hh:mm
    hinicio = "00:00"
    hfim = "23:00"

#substituindo os parametros comuns as estacoes
baseurl1 = gsub("&tipoArquivo=",paste0("&tipoArquivo=",tipo),baseurl1)
baseurl1 = gsub("&periodoInicial=",paste0("&periodoInicial=",dinicio,"T03:",hinicio,".000Z"),baseurl1)
baseurl1 = gsub("&periodoFinal=",paste0("&periodoFinal=",dfim,"T03:",hfim,".000Z"),baseurl1)

for(i in 1:length(CodigoEstacaoes)){ 
  baseurl1i = gsub("codigosEstacoes=",paste0("codigosEstacoes=",idEstacaoes[i]),baseurl1)
  baseurl2i = gsub("codigosEstacoes=",paste0("codigosEstacoes=",idEstacaoes[i]),baseurl2)

  #Conexao
  BROWSE(baseurl1i)
  BROWSE(baseurl2i) 
}
```

Comment: Interessante resposta! Sempre usei esse script. Mas noto que em alguns casos, para estações pluviométricas, muitos dados vem vazios, o que não ocorre no portal HidroWEB mesmo